# DSCP re-marking on Cisco Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, qos, policy-map

I've followed the commands in this post:
[DSCP trust boundary](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/dscp-trust-boundary?rq=1)

```
policy-map MARKDOWN
  class class-default
    set dscp ef
```

Interface Config:

```
interface gig 0/1
  service-policy input MARKDOWN
```

The commands went in fine on the Cisco switch I'm using, but it doesn't re-mark the DSCP field.

Switch I'm using is Cisco C2960 Ver 12.2(25r)SEE1.

1. is this just a possible bug
2. does this command work OK with other switches?

Comment: By default that switch with that code should remark all traffic to `BE`, which is what you seem to want to do, so what you are doing is really pointless. How are you determining the DSCP value on the packets leaving the switch?

Comment: You are marking the traffic as it's already marked.

Comment: sorry should be EF, not default,changed it.

Comment: You still need an access list to tell the switch what you want to mark. You cannot change the default class.

Comment: Check my post here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42660/implementing-cisco-qos-model-to-end-users?rq=1 Answer number two: *Marking incomming traffic based on port/type*

Comment: would a standard ACL matching an IP address suffice? where do I tie it up with the policy map there after? edit: checking that link now

Comment: Read the post, it's all explained there. Answer number two.I wouldn't know any way to explain it better.

Comment: You should think about upgrading your IOS. The software 12.2.25r is truncated years ago and contains very serious bugs in both the system and how it handles basic protocols.

Comment: most definitely... it's a lab switch that's been through the wars

Comment: @user10021657 did the post help out?

Comment: after trudging through all of that post.... it turns out what I described to begin with works and I was just missing `mls qos` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I managed to figure it out....

Turn on QoS using `switch(config)#mls qos` command

the original example now changes DSCP values from 0 to 46 ....

Mind you, this is for everything, but I can refine it with an ACL.

edit: I also realise that this is one interface, with `mls qos` it will default other interfaces to 0.... I've fixed this with another policy map which is the same as in the original example, except with a different name and `trust DSCP` instead of `set`

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.